# Como posso formatar dados para colocar em um arquivo csv

Tags: python, csv

Preciso passar vários dados extraídos para um arquivo csv porém quando faço isso fica tudo desconfigurado, pesquisei um pouco e não encontrei de fato o que precisava.

Segue abaixo o código que estou executando.

```
listainfo = ['\r\nName               Disabled\r\n----               --------\r\nAdmin                 False\r\nAdministrador          True\r\nAmanda    False\r\namanda.amanda   False\r\nConvidado              True\r\nDefaultAccount         True\r\nWDAGUtilityAccount     True\r\n\r\n\r\n']

with open("out.csv", "w", newline="", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(listainfo)
```

Entretanto quando faço isso fica tudo desconfigurado arquivo no arquivo csv

[image: É assim como ele aparece dentro do arquivo, todo desconfigurado e bem complicado de ler]

Gostaria de saber um jeito para formatar e ficar mais organizado, ex:

[image]

*** Os dados são obtidos através de uma API, segue abaixo onde recebo as infos e quais são os types delas.

```
 jsonResponse = chilkat2.JsonObject()
    jsonResponse.LoadSb(sbResponseBody)

    jsonResponse.EmitCompact = False
    #print(jsonResponse.Emit())
    test=json.loads(jsonResponse.Emit())
    test2=test["response"]["data"]["output"]

    print (type(test2))  str
    print (type(test))  dict
    print (type(jsonResponse.Emit())) str
    print (type(jsonResponse)) chilkat2.JsonObject
```

As informações que retiro são do "test2".

Segue abaixo o resultado de cada uma das informações test, test2, jsonResponse.Emit() e jsonResponse.

```
print (test)

{'files': [], 'id': '1414', 'command': '$UserAccounts = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter {LocalAccount = "True"} | select Name, Disabled \n\nWrite-Output $UserAccounts\n', 'name': 'Windows - List All Users | v1.0 JCCG', 'systemId': '123fa', 'organization': '5ba', 'user': 'root', 'sudo': False, 'requestTime': '2021-11-25T19:17:13.000Z', 'responseTime': '2021-11-25T19:17:14.000Z', 'response': {'id': '619fe1395ff92a18660b04e0', 'data': {'output': '\r\nName               Disabled\r\n----               --------\r\nAdmin                 False\r\nAdministrador          True\r\nAmanda    False\r\namanda.amanda    False\r\nConvidado              True\r\nDefaultAccount         True\r\nWDAGUtilityAccount     True\r\n\r\n\r\n', 'exitCode': 0}, 'error': ''}, 'workflowId': 'k12d23', 'workflowInstanceId': '', '_id': '4aaab', 'system': 'RC Amanda'}


print (test2)

Name               Disabled
----               --------
Admin                 False
Administrador          True
Amanda                False
amanda.amanda         False
Convidado              True
DefaultAccount         True
WDAGUtilityAccount     True



print (jsonResponse.Emit())

{
  "files": [
  ],
  "id": "aaaaaa",
  "command": "$UserAccounts = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter {LocalAccount = \"True\"} | select Name, Disabled \n\nWrite-Output $UserAccounts\n",
  "name": "Windows - List All Users | v1.0 JCCG",
  "systemId": "aaaaa",
  "organization": "bbbbb",
  "user": "root",
  "sudo": false,
  "requestTime": "2021-11-25T19:17:13.000Z",
  "responseTime": "2021-11-25T19:17:14.000Z",
  "response": {
    "id": "aaaaaa",
    "data": {
      "output": "\r\nName               Disabled\r\n----               --------\r\nAdmin                 False\r\nAdministrador          True\r\nAmanda    False\r\namanda.amanda    False\r\nConvidado              True\r\nDefaultAccount         True\r\nWDAGUtilityAccount     True\r\n\r\n\r\n",
      "exitCode": 0
    },
    "error": ""
  },
  "workflowId": "aaaaa",
  "workflowInstanceId": "",
  "_id": "bbbbbb",
  "system": "RC Amanda"
}


print (jsonResponse)
<chilkat2.JsonObject object at 0x00000247EE335CD4>
```

Comment: Você está mandando escrever apenas uma string no arquivo. Se quer estruturar em um CSV, precisará ter uma estrutura de dados mais organizada do que uma string.

Comment: Se tiver um dicionário, por exemplo, como `{'Admin': false, 'Administrador': true)` já simplifica bastante.

Comment: Que formato é esse em que se encontram os dados na string `listainfo`? Como obtém esses dados?

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei mais informações.

Comment: Faz um favor coloca também uma amostra do JSON que recebe da API. Agora estou com pouco tempo, mas daqui apouco eu passo aqui de novo e dou um retorno. Também confirma se essa tag [tag:python-2.7] está correta, pois estamos atualmente na versão Python 3.10

Comment: Já corrigi em relação a tag e também já adicionei as informações.

Comment: @Woss infelizmente vem da forma que passei.

Comment: Então terá que tratar a string antes de salvar em CSV. Possivelmente fazer um split por linhas e tratar linha a linha para obter cada coluna.

Comment: @GustavoAlves, veja se soluciona o seu problema: https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/CSVSplit#main.py

Comment: @AugustoVasques realmente funcionou, para 1 item. No caso quando eu tiver cerca de uns 100 resultados desses dentro da lista como eu colocaria ?

Comment: Depende do que são e o vai fazer com esses outros itens. Vão ser apensados na mesma tabela ou serão salvos em arquivos separados? Se forem apensados serão apensados como novas linhas ou serão novas colunas?

Comment: @AugustoVasques todos serão salvos na mesma tabela e o idela seria um abaixo do outro , ou seja, sendo criados em novas linhas.

Comment: Quando assim faça a pergunta incluindo tudo o que realmente precisa.

Comment: Segunda pergunta que eu faço, ainda ando meio perdido na plataforma.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Passando aqui pra avisar que só mudei pra append e deu tudo muito certo, muito obrigado por toda ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

O problema foi resolvido com ajuda do Augusto Vasques que comentou um código que me ajudou muito.

```
    url2 = "URL"+(i)

resp10 = requests.get(url2, headers=headers)
resp11 = resp10.json()
resp12 = resp11["response"]["data"]["output"]

with open("out.csv", "a", newline="", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in resp12.splitlines(keepends=False):
        writer.writerow(row.split())
```

Answer (score -3):

Com o comando `df.to_csv('file_name.csv')`, você sé precisaria usar a biblioteca Pandas. Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
import pandas as pd

name_dict = {
            'Name': ['Admin','Administrador','Amanda','amanda.amanda','Convidado', 'DefaltAccount],
            'Disable': ['FALSE','TRUE','FALSE','FALSE','TRUE','TRUE','TRUE']
          }

df = pd.DataFrame(name_dict)

df.to_csv('out.csv')

print (df)
```

Comment: Por que criar um dataframe apenas para gerar um csv?